# Verify constructor call in dart testing

Tags: dart, unit-testing, mockito, integration-testing

I have a class A that has a method b().

The method B creates the object C with some specific args and execute the d() method.

So A().b() calls C(specific args).d().

The signature of B and D methods are the same. A only exists to create C with those specifics Args. So it's kind of a proxy in order to be aligned to DRY and not call C(specific args) multiple times in different places + be more semantic. B is a generic name and D is a better name for my specific use case.

I already have all the tests written for A and B, but since C.d is a proxy to A.b that only specifies custom logic to the constructor, I don't want to retest everything again. I only want to make sure C was called with the correct arguments.

How could I do this with mockito or mocktail?

Comment: `package:mockito` and `package:mocktail` work by creating mock versions of classes that implement a specified interface.  In Dart, constructors and `static` methods are not part of an inheritable interface, so they cannot be mocked.  You instead could plumb through a callback that constructs `C` or some factory object that can construct `C` instances.